# File Uploading HTTP Server in Java

Tags: java, http, post

I am implementing an HTTP Server in Java. Currently, I am implementing a POST request handler.

I am facing issues in parsing the "multipart/form-data" file upload requests. I have tried several io stream but still the file arrives on the server in a garbled form.

I would like to know what are the best APIs to use and some links to demonstrated the actual file uploading scenario so that I can understand better.

Comment: If you are using spring then go for spring's MultiPartFile otherwise you can go for apache's Commons FileUpload.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cos=multipart.jar file if not for business purposes.
You can download it  [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcosmultipartjar.htm).
Read the [licence](http://www.servlets.com/cos/license.html) before using.

First Copy the jar file in the lib folder of the webcontent of your project in eclipse.
Then you can implement file upload as follows:

HTML/JSP code:

```
<form action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select File:<input type="file" name="image"/><br/>
<input type="submit" Value="Go"/>
</form>
```

Servlet code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest;

public class Upload extends HttpServlet 
{

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

      response.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,"D:/data");
      out.print("successfully uploaded");
   }
}
```

In order to get the values of other form fields use:

```
m.getParameter("param_name");  //m is the MultipartRequest object
```

instead of using HttpServletRequest object.

Hope this hepled.

Answer (score 0):

I use Apache commons-fileupload and it works perfectly,

You can read about how to use it in this link: http://www.devmedia.com.br/upload-de-arquivos-usando-commons-fileupload/3572

The article is in portuguese, if you need some example in english please tell me and I will make one

I hope it helps :D
Best regards

Comment: For Apache commons-fileupload, i need to implement a Servlet. I am implementing a Socket based server.